# In Javascript / ES6, how do I wait for Python code to finish executing in a Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: javascript, python, asynchronous, promise, jupyter-notebook

My code calls a Jupyter Notebook routine (kernel.execute) which accepts a Python command and a callback function but this routine doesn't return a Promise.

Is it possible to asynchronously call kernel.execute in a loop and wait on each callback?

```
// these functions print timestamps to the console
var function_1 = {
  iopub: {
    output: parse_json_from_python_and_stash_something_in_object_1();
  }
}

var function_n = {
  iopub: {
    output: parse_json_from_python_and_stash_something_in_object_n();
  }
}

var objects_to_populate = {
  object_1: function_1,
  object_n: function_n
}

handler.on('click', function() {

  $.each(objects_to_populate, function(obj, cb) {
    let arg = '\'' + "Hello from Javascript" + '\'';
    let command = `print(${arg})`;

    // Jupyter Notebook function; calls Python (slow)
    kernel.execute(command, cb);
  }

  ugly_sleep_hack();
  // Do something here after every object has been populated

  print_timestamp_to_console("Finished");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use es6 `async`, `await` for that:

```js
// emulating async function here
let kernel = {
  execute: (ignore, cb) => setTimeout(cb, 2000)
}

let objects_to_populate = {
  1: () => console.log(1),
  2: () => console.log(2),
  3: () => console.log(3)
};

let execute = function(command, cb) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    kernel.execute(command, function() {
      cb();
      resolve();
    });
  })
};

let handler = $('#testBtn');

handler.on('click', async function() {
      let executes = [];


      $.each(objects_to_populate, function(obj, cb) {
      
          let arg = '\'' + "Hello from Javascript" + '\'';
          let command = `print(${arg})`;

          // Jupyter Notebook function; calls Python (slow)
          executes.push(execute(command, cb));
        });

        await Promise.all(executes);
        console.log('Something');
        // Do something here after every object has been populated
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="testBtn">Test</button>
```

Comment: I am not sure I clearly understand your problem, You want to run all the async function in the same time (in the loop) and wait until all the async function are finished, and continue from there?

Comment: Yes. The order in which the functions execute isn't important, except that I want to wait on all of them to finish before continuing beneath the loop. With this async / await pattern, if I printed something to console outside the loop, it would arrive before the callback functions execute.

Comment: Using your recent edit, "Finished" prints after 44ms, function_1 prints after 300ms, function_2 after 400ms, etc. Kernel.execute returns a hash, not a promise. This is the root of my problem

Comment: @W.Bernbaum Edited :)

Comment: This solution really seems like it should work!! But it awaits forever. print_timestamp_to_console("Finished") is never called

Comment: DId you tried with only 1 `kernel.execute` and 2 etc.... I don't know it is a back end or my code, `kernel.execute` always call the callback?

Comment: In the previous version you suggested (await inside the loop), `kernel.execute` called the callbacks and logged/printed success for each of them. Edit: I added logging and for each call, a promise is returned, but the callback never executes and the promise doesn't resolve

Comment: @W.Bernbaum I edited the answer one more time, I added `kernel.execute` as an async function, and simple callbacks to `objects_to_populate ` it is works for me, I think there is another error  in your code somewhere else.

Comment: You're right, this answers the question as asked & should definitely be the accepted solution. I'll take another look at my code. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Also you can write and use recursive function. Here https://mostafa-samir.github.io/async-iterative-patterns-pt1/ you can find some explanations. Something like that:

```js
var objects_to_populate = {
  object_1: function_1,
  object_n: function_n
};

const iterateAsync = (collection, keys, i) => {
  if (i < keys.length){
    const obj = collection[keys[i]]; // This is your obj
    const arg = '\'' + "Hello from Javascript" + '\'';
    const command = `print(${arg})`;

    // Jupyter Notebook function; calls Python (slow)
    executes.push(execute(command, (err, res) => {
      if(!err){
        i++;
        iterateAsync(collection, keys, i);
      }
    }));
  }
};

const keys = Object.keys(objects_to_populate); // To create it once
iterateAsync(objects_to_populate, keys, 0);
```

I don't test it, but you need something like that.

Comment: Recursive function + queue will solve that problem, what you mean when talking about irrelevancy?

Comment: [Are answers that just contain links elsewhere really “good answers”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/378063)

Comment: Okay, guys, agreed